# &&str.to_owned() doesn't result in a String

Tags: reference, rust

I've got the following code:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;
fn main() {
    let xs: Vec<&str> = vec!("a", "b", "c", "d");
    let ys: Vec<i32> = vec!(1, 2, 3, 4);

    let mut map: HashMap<String,i32> = HashMap::new();
    for (x,y) in xs.iter().zip(ys) {
        map.insert(x.to_owned(), y);
    }
    println!("{:?}", map);
}
```

Which results in error:

```
<anon>:8:20: 8:32 error: mismatched types:
 expected `collections::string::String`,
    found `&str`
(expected struct `collections::string::String`,
    found &-ptr) [E0308]
<anon>:8         map.insert(x.to_owned(), y);
```

But it doesn't make sense to me. `x` should be `&&str` at this point. So why doesn't `&&str.to_owned()` automagically `Deref` the same way `x.to_string()` does at this point? (Why is `x.to_owned()` a `&str`?)

I know I can fix this by either using `x.to_string()`, or `xs.into_iter()` instead.

Comment: These work: `map.insert((**x).to_owned(), y);` and `map.insert((*x).to_owned(), y);`. I think it has something to do with the fact that Rust cannot insert more than one `*` in some cases, but I don't remember when.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because `ToOwned` is implemented `for T where T: Clone`, and `Clone` is implemented `for &T`. You need to roughly understand how pattern matching on `&self` works when both `T` and `&T` are available. Using a pseudo-syntax for exposition,

### `str → String`

- `str` doesn't match `&self`
- `&str` (auto-ref) matches `&self` with `self == str`

Thus `ToOwned<str>` kicks in.

### `&str → String`

- `&str` matches `&self` with `self == str`

Thus `ToOwned<str>` kicks in.

### `&&str → &str`

- `&&str` matches `&self` with `self == &str`

Thus `ToOwned<&T>` kicks in.

Note that in this case, auto-*deref* can never kick in, since `&T` will always match in cases where `T` might, which lowers the complexity a bit. Note also that auto-ref only kicks in once (and once more for each auto-deref'd type).

To copy from [huon's much better answer than mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28519997/what-are-rusts-exact-auto-dereferencing-rules/28552082#28552082),

> The core of the algorithm is:
>
> - For each [each "dereference step"](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/b6d91a2bdac45cd919497a24207fab843124d4ba/src/librustc_typeck/check/method/probe.rs#L166-L196) `U` (that is, set `U = T` and then `U = *T`, ...)
>
>   1. if there's a method `bar` where the receiver type (the type of `self` in the method) matches `U` exactly , use it ([a "by value method"](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/b6d91a2bdac45cd919497a24207fab843124d4ba/src/librustc_typeck/check/method/probe.rs#L793))
>   2. otherwise, add one auto-ref (take `&` or `&mut` of the receiver), and, if some method's receiver matches `&U`, use it ([an "autorefd method"](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/b6d91a2bdac45cd919497a24207fab843124d4ba/src/librustc_typeck/check/method/probe.rs#L798))

---

FWIW, `.into()` is normally prettier than `.to_owned()` (especially when types are implied; oft even when not), [so I suggest that here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=4df3cc2d82462175045a&version=stable). You still need a manual dereference, though.